# Does the [ɒ] in "not" sound different from the [ɒ] in "hot"?

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, phonetics

I would like to know why the [ɒ] in *not* often sounds different (more rounded) than the [ɒ] in *hot*, *fathe*r, or *car* in American English.

I know that in British English the vowel in *not* is an [ɔ], but I've been taught that in American English it is an [ɒ], as in *hot*. However, I've noticed that the majority of Americans do not pronounce the vowel in *not* exactly the same as the vowel in *hot*; most of them produce a more rounded (and sometimes shorter) sound, similar to an [ɔ], as in *dog*.

For example, in the phrase *It's not like that* the [ɒ] in *not* is usually pronounced quickly and more rounded, as if it were almost a British [ɔ].

Why is this so?

Comment: I (in the US) don't pronounce the vowel sounds of the two identically, but it's *very* close, probably not enough difference to be noticed unless you're specifically listening.  I detect more of an "ah" sound in "hot".  I kind of sense that this difference occurs because the mouth was previously configured to make the "h" sound and doesn't quite return to "neutral" before the vowel -- not really intentional, but simply due to speech mechanics.  It's harder to say about "father" and "car".

Comment: I pronounce not the same as hot, knot, cot, bot, and got.

Comment: You seem to think that all Americans talk alike. We don't. I don't pronounce *not* differently from *hot*. But it's quite possible that some American use the vowel of *caught* and *dog* for *not*. Where are the Americans you're hearing this from?

Comment: What region of the US are you referring to? I pronounce them the same in the midwest. There are some regional accents that elongate the sound - like "nawt" - but they would do the same with both words.

Comment: I pronounce the vowels in hot, father, and car all slightly differently, but hot is the same as not, and I'm from New Jersey.

Comment: (The difference is in how nasal it is. Hot, father, and car are ranked in increasing order of nasalness.)

Comment: New Jersey?  Well that explains it!  ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my experience (SE US), I don't hear this.  The [ɒ] in *not* is pronounced the same as in *hot*.  In the word "naughty", I do sometime here the British pronunciation, I suspect because of the "augh".  This happens even more with "haughty", again, I suspect because of the "augh" and possibly avoid confusion with obscure (in the US) slang word "hotty".

Answer (score 2):

In a sentence the O would definitely sound shorter (American English). It's still subtle to my ear, though. You can still hear the "aw" sound.

Answer (score 1):

Have you been listening to a lot of British English? In British English, one of the major differences between /ɒ/ (*not, hot*) on the one hand and /ɔː/ (*caught*) and /ɑː/ (*path*) on the other, is that /ɒ/ is shorter. Most Americans don't pronounce the vowel in *not* any differently than the vowel in *hot*, but we often shorten the vowel in *not*, because it's a function word. So maybe you're hearing this length difference and assigning the vowel to /ɒ/.